# Dev Tool clearly showing json response but not on browser / postman / python request etc

Tags: json, angular, xmlhttprequest, cloudflare, firefox-developer-tools

[image]

please mark this question as dumb if you should, because i really feel dumb .
i check this link https://www.instaforex.com/specifications/currencies?account=standard&instrument=currencies&page=1, on Dev Tool it clearly show giving json response. But why it showing HTML response on browser / postman / python request etc?
what prevent this from giving json response? is it cloudflare? / angular? / jquery? / cors? please give me an enlightenment. thank you very much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

now i know about sec-fetch-site 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Site